# Adding pages to the Admin panel

Tags: customization, admin, page-template

Instead of going to Pages on the Admin panel nav bar on the left to see all the pages that are created. I would Like the pages to show up on the Admin panel nav bar it self. Like a custom post type. How can I do this. Any help would be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you are trying to add a new menu to the Admin Panel. For that, the following tutorial would be one of the best for you to such:

> - **[The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/)** (Part I - VIII)

The key things are:

- [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)
- [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)
- [`add_theme_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page) - for theme options
- [`add_plugins_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_plugins_page) - for plugin